# Boostrap child modal on opening fires parent modal open event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Following is parent modal code (code 1):

```
$('#modal_parent').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  .....
})
```

Following is how I open a modal inside "modal_parent" by calling Js function (code 2):

```
function editEntry(id){
  $("#childmodal").modal();
}
```

Now, when code 2 is executed, why is code 1 also getting executed?
In short, when child modal is opened in a parent, why does parent modal opening code also get fired? Both these modals have different `id`s as shown above.

Any custom code suggestions so as not to fire code 1 when code 2 gets executed ?

Comment: Something to keep in mind for this kind of question: Bootstrap specifically states that showing multiple/nested modals is not supported without custom code, so you should probably *include* the custom code you're using to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive this will work, but you may give this a try:

```
$("#childmodal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

See [the docs here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)